# How to close socket for particular client in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, connection

Server is connected to couple of client. Client send message bye to server. If server close its socket it loose connection to other clients. Do I need to inform server that client is off and How to close it for particular client in following simple example:

Server:

```
#include "wrappers.h"
int main(){

  unsigned int Sockfd, NewSockfd, ClntLen;
  sockaddr_in ClntAddr, ServAddr;
  int Port = SERV_TCP_PORT;
  char String[MAX_SIZE];
  int Len;

  // open a TCP socket (an Internet stream socket)
  Sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // socket() wrapper fn

  // bind the local address, so that the client can send to server
  memset((char*)&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));
  ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  ServAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);

  Bind(Sockfd, (sockaddr*) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));

  // listen to the socket
  Listen(Sockfd, 5);

  for(;;){
     // wait for a connection from a client; this is an iterative server
     ClntLen = sizeof(ClntAddr);
     NewSockfd = Accept(Sockfd, (sockaddr*)&ClntAddr, &ClntLen);

     if(NewSockfd < 0){
        perror("Can't bind local address!");
     }

     // read a message from the client
     Len = read(NewSockfd, String, MAX_SIZE);
     String[Len] = 0;// make sure it's a proper string
     printf("%s\n", String);


     write(NewSockfd, "hello", sizeof("hello"));
     cout<<"wrote to client"<<endl;

     close(NewSockfd);
  }
}
```

Client:

```
#include "wrappers.h"

int main()
{
  int Sockfd;
  sockaddr_in ServAddr;
  char ServHost[] = "localhost";
  hostent *HostPtr;
  int Port = SERV_TCP_PORT;
  int BuffSize = 0;

  // get the address of the host
  HostPtr = Gethostbyname(ServHost);

  if(HostPtr->h_addrtype !=  AF_INET){
     perror("Unknown address type!");
     exit(1);
  }

  memset((char *) &ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));
  ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)HostPtr->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
  ServAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
  bool loop = true;

  int i= 0;
  while(loop){


      // open a TCP socket
      Sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

      // connect to the server
      Connect(Sockfd, (sockaddr*)&ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));


      if(i>5){
          loop = false;
      }
      i++;
      // write a message to the server
      write(Sockfd, "hello world", sizeof("hello world"));

      char String[10];
      int Len = read(Sockfd, String, MAX_SIZE);
      String[Len] = 0;// make sure it's a proper string
      printf("%s === \n", String);

  }


  close(Sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Sooo much code. Can you provide a reduced example of your problem?

Comment: confused about what you want? Are you want like if server closed then inform all client to close?

Comment: @Jayesh I just want to know when client is shut down for any reason. How to call server to close the socket for that particular client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `client` socket is closed, you will get return value 0 at server side from `read`.this is the indication for end of client connection.

If you try to `write` to such a socket, you will recieve the `SIGPIPE` signal, and the `write` will return error with `errno` set to `EPIPE` ("Broken Pipe").